# How to get the address of KiFastCallEntry from windows wdm driver

Tags: windows, c

Hi i want to hook the KiFastCallEntry function from my Windows Driver , but i dont know how to get the addrres of this function , can someone pls tell me how?

Target OS is Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__readmsr(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y55zyfdx.aspx)[`IA32_SYSENTER_EIP )`](http://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER#MSRs)

Comment: __readmsr undefined ? What header do i Need to use? Note, i need to get the address from kernel mode...

Comment: You need to `#include <intrin.h>`.

Comment: IA32_SYSENTER_EIP undefined ...... ?

Comment: In my original post, I linked to the documentation for `__readmsr()`, which shows what header you need to include, and I linked to documentation on `IA32_SYSENTER_EIP`, which shows its numeric value.

Comment: ok thx very much you helped me alot